# how to send a file in cakephp3?

Tags: cakephp-3.0

myappI have to reply with a file in cakePHP3 and in a particular case, it seems that I have a problem, maybe of header.

I want to send an APK (Android package) file.
So if I directly access to the file online, there is no problem but I want to send it from my controller and the file seems to not be considered as a 'raw' apk file.

Here is my code:

```
public function getmyappapk()
{

    $this->request->allowMethod([
        'get'
    ]);

    $this->response->type('application/apk');
    $this->response->file(WWW_ROOT . DS. 'tmp' .DS. 'app-release.apk',
        ['download' => true, 'name' => 'MyApp.apk']);

    return $this->response;
}
```

so as I said, if I access to www.mywebsite.com/tmp/app-release.apk, from my smartphone, it downloads it and I can install it.

But if I access to www.mywebsite.com/mycontroller/getmyappapk, it downloads the file and then, tells me that it's impossible to open it.

The type 'application/apk' seems to be ok because if I enter the url in a browser it tells me to record the file recognised as 'android packet'.
But something is certainly missing here.

What is the problem?

Comment: Well, I'd say you should do some debugging, starting with comparing the headers of the two requests, followed by doing a binary comparison of the download packages. If there's nothing suspicious, continue with comparing the requests that the server receives.

Comment: @ndm thanks ndm but I don't see how to verify the request/header received by the server in the case I give the direct file's url.. When you talk about the binary comparison that lets me think that the file maybe zipped no? Is it the case when I reply from my controller?